# Carrying crampons safely when not using them

Tags: mountaineering, gear-care, crampons

How should one carry crampons when not actually using it, but knowing that they are going to be needed in the further stage of the expedition.

Further clarification: Suppose I am gonna need to have crampons on only in a certain stage of the expedition, and not all the way.

What is the best possible safe way to carry them they don't damage my backpack?
I am not in favor of tying them outside the pack, as they may get damaged and I personally don't like things tied to the pack when it can be avoided.

Comment: How soon is "a further stage" -  hours or days? If hours, safest is outside where they are quick and easy to get to when next needed. Nothing worse than the "it will take 10 minutes to get them out, its only 20 meters of rock hard ice decision......

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Collapse them down, sandwich them with the points facing each inwards, and wrap the straps around them.  You can then use a "real" crampon bag to hold them, or improvise.  Some ideas for packaging them include:

- Cut the top off a 2 liter soda bottle (use two bottles for full containment).
- Make or buy a heavy (e.g. 500D) cordura nylon bag.
- Cut off an old denim pant leg and slide them inside.
- Wrap them in a towel or similar padding.
- Nothing at all, just keep them away from anything especially delicate.

Also keep in mind that while they may be nice and clean on the way in, coming out they will be muddy and slushy.  My pack has a crampon patch and straps, so that's where I carry them.

Further discussion and images can be found here:
http://www.backpackinglight.com/cgi-bin/backpackinglight/forums/thread_display.html?forum_thread_id=84284

Comment: I tried the soda bottle. Totally didn't fit.

Comment: Depends on crampons. C1 is fine in 2L Coke bottle.

Comment: +1 crampon bag. I'd recommend some tarp-like fabric you could wrap around the crampons (like in this [picture](http://campsupply.co.th/deuter/product_model/model_pict/frontview/50461327c2cf1.jpg)). Goal is to keep the melting snow from getting everywhere, and protect your backpack from pointy stuff!

Comment: If you can't be bothered making one of these, you can also buy something for this, such as a [Grivel crampon safe](http://www.grivel.com/products/ice/accessories/81-crampon_safe)

Comment: I have to confess, I love my crampon safe! It has ventilation holes, some straps on the outside which allow to hang it somewhere (harness, backpack, whatever), does not look like it could be pierced by the sharpest crampon tips (extra reinforcement where the front tips should point to) and although it is quite compact there's room for some two or three ice screws in addition to the crampons.

Answer (score 3):

Just face the pointy bits towards each other and wrap the webbing around the bundle to keep them together. I then just chuck them in the bottom of my bag if I know I don't need them or in the top if I know I will. You could pad them with a hat, spare socks or what ever if you were worried about other more delicate items.

Also even if they start out sharp once they've encountered a small amount of scrambling or walking up some moraine they're unlikely to be sharp enough to damage something unless you're being very forceful in your packing / unpacking.

[image: packed crampons]